# how to include libcurl libaries inside the built exe?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, merge, executable, libcurl

I need to include libcurl files inside the built file(vs++ project) so the user doesn't have to download them. I have been looking for an answer for quite some time now without success, please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can [build the source code yourself](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/install.html).  The source code is [here](http://curl.haxx.se/dev/source.html).

You can distribute files like `libeay32.dll` with your app, in which case libcurl is built with dynamic linking. You can either build them yourself (as said before), or you can [download pre-built ones](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html).

If you don't want to distribute files like `libeay32.dll` and instead have the libcurl code embedded into your .exe or .dll, this is called static linking, and you can build the source code that way as well.